# django-storages aws s3 costs reduction and calculation

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

i would like to calculate and reduce my costs for my file storage on s3.

I have deploy my django app to elastic beanstalk in Europa (Frankfurt) eu-central-1. At the moment i use a t2.micro ec2 instance, a db.t2.micro PostgreSQL database and a additional standard s3 bucket beside the standard bucket from elastic beanstalk.

I think the cost for the ec2 and the database are easy manageable because after the free tier i would like to use reserved instances. But the s3 costs make me worry.

Users can upload and download files to my application. My django application use django-storages to manage the files but i don't know what happened in the background and for what i must pay.

For example i have a storage class and a model with a file field:

```
class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'private'
    default_acl = 'private'
    custom_domain = False
    
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    
class FileDocument(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey('documents.Document', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="files")
    file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    ...
```

**- - Upload**

I store files thats a user upload like this:

```
document = Document.objects.get(...)

files = request.FILES.getlist('files[]')

if files:
    for file in files:
        try:
            file_obj = FileDocument.objects.get(name=file.name, document=document)
            file_obj.file.save(file.name, file)
            file_obj.save()
        except FileDocument.DoesNotExist:
            file_obj = FileDocument()
            file_obj.name = file.name
            file_obj.document = document
            file_obj.file.save(file.name, file)
            file_obj.save()
...
```

I think this could be a PUT request for that i must pay 0,0054 USD / 1000 requests in my zone. Right?

**- - Download**

If a user would like to download a file, i return an url:

```
...
file = get_object_or_404(FileDocument, pk=pk)
return Response({'url': file.file.url, })
```

Which request is this? A GET request?
A GET request costs 0,00043 USD / 1000 requests. But if the user open the returned url is that also a GET request?

**- - Get all files**

In the frontend the user get a list of all files that belongs to a specific document. At the moment i return the list of files for a document like so:

```
document = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=pk)
serializer = FileDocumentSerializer(document.files.all(), many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

I use a django rest framework serializer for this:

```
class FileDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileDocument
        exclude = ['document',]
```

Which kind of request is this? Also a GET request for every file in `document.files.all()`?
In the frontend only the name is important. If i store the name of the file in the `FileDocument` model additionally and exclude the `file` field in the serializer than no GET request send? Could this reduce the costs?

I think it is very tricky to calculate the costs if i don't understand when and what kind of requests send by django storages.

I know that i have not talk about the costs for database and file storage space. I think i can ignore the storage costs because at this point i can't reduce the costs without limit the user experience. Furthermore at the beginning i plan with 100 or 150 users and i think each user upload less than 1 GB.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks for that question. I have VERY similar worries. The only possible answer is to explore the code of django-storages, which I intend to do rapidly.

Answer (score -1):

you can make use of the cost calculator provided by aws https://calculator.aws/. Create an estimate and use the resource as s3.

You can put in your file transfer size, no. of requests and data existing over s3 and you can get an estimate along with the calculations that led to the estimate.

And any request to the s3 to fetch any data is a get request

Comment: I know the calculation tool but that can't help me if i don't understand which requests use for which action by django-storages. So `file_obj.file.save(file.name, file)` is a PUT request and return the url `file.file.url` a GET request. But does the `FileDocumentSerializer` also a GET request? And when yes can i reduce the GET requests if i exclude the file field from the serializer?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I'm the right person for this question. Apologies.